# In memory key/value store using integer keys (not string hashes)

Tags: database

I have a large amount of `integer => string` values that I want stored in a RAM on a smaller server. However, it seems that data stores like membase and redis hash the key resulting in a key that is much larger to store than a integer. (I assume they do this since they assume keys will contain strings and need to be setup for scaling to multiple nodes).

Are there any key stores that use integer keys so I can cram a few million objects into just a few megabytes of memory? I would also like it to flush to disk every once in a while if possible.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of memory used will be far more dependent on the size of the string values than the keys, given that even if you're storing a 32-bit integer as a string it can take a maximum of 10 bytes.  Sure, that's 2.5 times the storage, but how small are your values in that case?

I'm inclined to think that you're optimising at the wrong level; hardware is cheap, throwing a bit more RAM at a problem is likely to be far more cost-effective than trying to find a very, very specialised data store (and, in all likelihood, by "find" I mean "write and maintain it yourself").

Comment: I guess that is true, I looked but I couldn't find one. However, storing a 32-bit key (~4 billion) is actually 4x smaller than a 128 bit MD5 (or 160 bit sha1) key hash. The values are either very small strings or integers themselves so they size of the key really does make a difference. Still, I guess I don't have much choice but to throw more RAM at it.